# Direct wrong flag input

Tags: bash, shell, if-statement

I have a bash script that takes any of a bunch of flags. I want it to direct empty or wrong input (input that doesn't match any of the flags) to some show_help function. I've got the empty input part down, and when running the script with wrong flags I get the error for wrong input. But - when running with proper flags, I still get the error for wrong input.

I figure that something's wrong with my `elif` statement.. do I need to use commas between the values? Something else?

The script:

```
f_read_input "$@"

# direct wrong or empty flag input to show help
if [ -z "$@" ]; then
  echo "Please enter at least one flag (you entered none)."
  echo
  f_show_help
elif [ "$@" != $FLAG_HELP,$FLAG_TARLogs,$FLAG_TARResrc,$FLAG_DELLogs,$FLAG_TAREncod,$FLAG_DELResrc,$FLAG_DELEncod ]; then
  echo "One or more of the flags entered are wrong. Please check your spelling and see the list of flags below."
  echo
#  f_show_help
fi
```

Comment: Use getopts or getopt or a case statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while getopts ahs: option
do
     case "$option"
     in
        $FLAG_HELP) code/function;;
        $FLAG_TARLogs) code/function;;
        $FLAG_TARResrc) code/function ;;
        $FLAG_DELLogs) code/function;;
        $FLAG_TAREncod) code/function;;
        $FLAG_DELResrc) code/function;;
        $FLAG_DELEncod) code/function;;
        h) DisplayUsage
       exit 0;;
        ?) DisplayUsage
       exit 1;;
     esac
done 2>/dev/null
```

Display function contains the options and how they are used..

```
DisplayUsage()
{
 echo
 echo
 echo "Options are "
 echo 
 echo
 echo
 echo
}
```

Comment: Is there no way to compare @$ to value1 or 2 or 3 (something like @$ != value1 'or' 2 'or' 3)?

Comment: save the options in a list then try using this

`[[ $list =~ $@ ]] && echo 'yes' || echo 'no'`

yes means correct option no means incorrect